# Is there a way to embed Stripe's STPPaymentCardTextField inside Eureka form builder?

Tags: ios, swift, forms, eureka-forms

How do I add STPPaymentCardTextField in the [Eureka](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka) form builder?

According to the documentation, you can add a UIView like so:

```
form +++
     Section(footer: "Credit or Debit Card"){ section in
          section.header = {
               var header = HeaderFooterView<STPPaymentCardTextField>(.callback({
                    return self.paymentField
               }))
          header.height = { 60 }
          return header
     }()
}
```

But the problem arises when the keyboard is displayed and the row doesn't behave as a row but a view so it stays on the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out. I created a library for those interested: https://github.com/Slugbug/Eureka-StripeRow

I solved the problem by subclassing. Also this code `formViewController()?.beginEditing(of: self)` was necessary to notify an update of cell.